# AssignProcessToJobObject return false with error ACCESS_DENIED when a process handle is added

Tags: c#, winapi, process

I have a console app which runs in administrator context and I want to launch a child process in current user's context. I have the following code to achieve this -

```
private static bool RunAsCurrentUser(string fileName, string arguments)
        {
           
            var hProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                var process = GetCurrentProcess();
                if (!OpenProcessToken(process, 0x0020, ref hProcessToken))
                    return false;

                var tkp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
                {
                    PrivilegeCount = 1,
                    Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1]
                };

                if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", ref tkp.Privileges[0].Luid))
                    return false;

                tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0x00000002;

                if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcessToken, false, ref tkp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                    return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
            }

           
            var hwnd = NativeMethods.GetShellWindow();
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                return false;

            var hShellProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            var hShellProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            var hPrimaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                // Get the PID of the desktop shell process.
                uint dwPID;
                if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out dwPID) == 0)
                    return false;

                // Open the desktop shell process in order to query it (get the token)
                hShellProcess = OpenProcess(NativeMethods.ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, false, dwPID);
                if (hShellProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return false;

                // Get the process token of the desktop shell.
                if (!OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 0x0002, ref hShellProcessToken))
                    return false;
                var dwTokenRights = 395U;

               CreateProcessWithTokenW (contrary to current documentation).
                if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hShellProcessToken, dwTokenRights, IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, NativeMethods.TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out hPrimaryToken))
                    return false;
                int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
                short SW_SHOW = 5;
                // Start the target process with the new token.
                var si = new STARTUPINFO();
                var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
                si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
                si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\default";
                si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
                si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
                string finalArgs = $"\"{fileName}\" {arguments}";               
                if (! (hPrimaryToken, 0, fileName, finalArgs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), ref si, out pi))
                    return false;                
                ChildProcessTracker.AddProcessHandle(pi.dwProcessId);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception) { return false; }
            finally
            {
                NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hShellProcessToken);
                NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hPrimaryToken);
                NativeMethods.CloseHandle(hShellProcess);
            }

        }
```

To track the process once it is launched I have the following code

```
public static void AddProcessHandle(IntPtr handle)
        {
            if (s_jobHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                bool success = AssignProcessToJobObject(s_jobHandle, handle);
                if (!success)
                    throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }


        static ChildProcessTracker()
        {
           
            string jobName = "MyProcess" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            s_jobHandle = CreateJobObject(IntPtr.Zero, jobName);

            var info = new JobobjectBasicLimitInformation();
           
            info.LimitFlags = JOBOBJECTLIMITS.KillOnJobClose;

            var extendedInfo = new JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation();
            extendedInfo.BasicLimitInformation = info;
            int length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation));
            IntPtr extendedInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
            try
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(extendedInfo, extendedInfoPtr, false);

                SetInformationJobObject(s_jobHandle, JobObjectInfoType.ExtendedLimitInformation,
                    extendedInfoPtr, (uint)length);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(extendedInfoPtr);
            }
        }
```

When AddProcessHandle method is called after launching the process using CreateProcessWithTokenW native method, it returns false and I am not able to track the process.

When AddProcessHandle method is called after launching the process using CreateProcessWithTokenW native method, it returns false and I am not able to track the process.

Expected: The process handle should be assigned to the JobObject and it should be killed when the console app is killed.

Comment: `AddProcessHandle(pi.dwProcessId);` when must be `AddProcessHandle(pi.hProcess);` also why you use `CreateProcessWithTokenW` ? when you need open process for get it token - use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` but not `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`. create process in suspended state, assign to job, and resume. check for AdjustTokenPrivileges, and more..

Comment: I tried passing AddProcessHandle(pi.hProcess) , still getting the same error.